# How can I access the last built revision according to jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, gradle

Near the top of my build console I see a "Last Built Revision:" w/ a revision #.  How can I access this last built rev # in my build script?  I'm using Gradle, but I don't think that matters here.  Does Jenkins provide the last built rev # in a system property?  Surely this must be trivial to access from my build script...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think the git plugin exports the last built revision as an environment variable, but the information is easily available using a simple shell command like:

```
curl -sf "$BUILD_URL/api/xml?xpath=//lastBuiltRevision/SHA1/text()"
```

BUILD_URL always points to the build's own page and the rest of the information seems to be available using the xml api.

Answer (score 12):

You can directly access the Jenkins `BUILD_NUMBER` as system environment variable.

```
task getBuildNumber << {
    ext.env = System.getenv()
    ext.buildNumber = env.BUILD_NUMBER?.toInteger()
    println "Build Number: $buildNumber"
}
```

Comment: `env.BUILD_NUMBER` does not contain the VCS revision, but Jenkins' build's number. That's useful in some cases, but as far as I can tell it's not what the OP is asking for

Comment: The build number is also not unique across branches in a multibranch pipeline. This means that if you want to use it to create unique variable names for your builds, they will only be unique within a branch. Not across multiple branches.

Answer (score 12):

Turns out, the Git plugin DOES export the last build revision as an environment variable. So instead of using the accepted answer:

```
curl -sf "$BUILD_URL/api/xml?xpath=//lastBuiltRevision/SHA1/text()"
```

you can just use this instead:

```
GIT_PREVIOUS_COMMIT
```

One failproof way to see exactly what's available to your build script is to choose `Add Build Step > Execute Shell` then simply add the following:

```
export
```

view your console (for the build) and you should see lots of great environment variables available to you. The git-related variables that were available to me (using the git plugin) were:

```
GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL
GIT_AUTHOR_NAME
GIT_BRANCH
GIT_COMMIT
GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL
GIT_COMMITTER_NAME
GIT_PREVIOUS_COMMIT
GIT_URL
```

Lastly, to see a less comprehensive list of available environment variables, you can also just go to this url: `http://[your-jenkins-domain-and-port]/env-vars.html`

Comment: Note that these variables are not available (yet) under the pipeline plugin, awaiting resolution of  [JENKINS-35230 The environment variables of git plugin not working in pipeline script](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-35230)

Answer (score 3):

The current build-number is provided as the Jenkins-variable **BUILD_NUMBER**

- In Unix it is set for you as **${BUILD_NUMBER}**
- In Windows it is available as **%BUILD_NUMBER%**

The complete list of variables is available on your Jenkins server, at:
 http://[your-jenkins-server]/**env-vars.html**

Comment: Commenting here since this is the correct answer for getting the Jenkins build number. If however your question was about the Revision number of a Mercurial repository, then you'll want to execute the following command from within a clone repository "hg id -n" and then direct the output appropriately (ie, read it into a variable or log file.

Answer (score 2):

The Git plugin returns information from the `checkout()` command. In Pipeline script, this can be used to get the previous commit:

```
def scmVars = checkout scm

scmVars.GIT_PREVIOUS_COMMIT
```