# Git environment variables for use in executing Jenkins shell scripts

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, cloudbees

Hope someone can help - I have the following plugin installed in my Jenkins instance - but I don't seem to be able to get hold of the Git variables below. I need these to complete our CI setup. Is there something that I'm missing?

I'm passing them in like:

ssh builder@10.10.10.10 "./build-pass.sh $GIT_BRANCH"

```
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin
```

### Environment variables

The git plugin sets several environment variables you can use in your scripts:

- GIT_COMMIT - SHA of the current
- GIT_BRANCH - Name of the branch currently being used, e.g. "master" or "origin/foo"
- GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL - Committer/Author Email
- GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL - Committer/Author Email

Comment: Are you running that ssh command from inside a Jenkins build (where the GIT_ variables should be available), or from a command line (where they won't be) ?

Answer (score 23):

Ok I cracked this one myself.

To see all environment variables available add to the Execute shell field:

```
printenv
```

Console output will then show all the available vars.

Comment: You can also use the `env` command.  But it's still not showing up for me..

Answer (score 6):

Please also have a look at:
[How can I access the last built revision according to jenkins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11526672/how-can-i-access-the-last-built-revision-according-to-jenkins)

The part with the env-vars url was really helpful:

> Lastly, to see a less comprehensive list of available environment variables, you can also just go to this url: http://[your-jenkins-domain-and-port]/env-vars.html

Answer (score 0):

Similarly you could just echo them out:

```
echo GIT_COMMIT %GIT_COMMIT% 
echo GIT_BRANCH %GIT_BRANCH%
```

[image]

Here's a quick [Jenkins Git configuration tutorial](https://www.theserverside.com/blog/Coffee-Talk-Java-News-Stories-and-Opinions/Complete-Jenkins-Git-environment-variables-list-for-batch-jobs-and-shell-script-builds) on the Git environment variables topic that uses the Jenkins Git configuration described in the image.