# SCM environment variables missing

Tags: jenkins-workflow

Usually, when using SCM like the *Git Plugin*, there are a bunch of environment variables that you can use (e.g. [see these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24746051/git-environment-variables-for-use-in-executing-jenkins-shell-scripts))

But neither the *Git Step* nor the *Generic SCM* seem to do that.

Is there a way to get these variables into the groovy `env.*` so that they can be used?

Something like this would be useful:

```
def commitMessage = sh 'git log --max-count=1 --oneline --no-merges | cut -b9-'
```

I can think of writing the results to a file and read them via the `readFile()` mehtod -- but is there an easier way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [JENKINS-24141](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-24141); these variables are not yet available from Workflow.

In the meantime, you are on the right track: run a `git` command to record any information you need, and use `readFile` to load it (see also [JENKINS-26133](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-26133)).

Answer (score 3):

For the Record: I have the following code to get the branch-name:

```
stage 'preparation'
node {
 // checkout branch
  git branch: 'origin/master', url: 'git@example.net:project.git'

  // write current branch-name to file
  sh 'git branch -a --contains `git rev-parse HEAD` | grep origin | sed \'s!\\s*remotes/origin/\\(.*\\)!\\1!\' > git-branch.txt'

  // read data from file into environment-variable
  env.gitBranch = readFile('git-branch.txt').trim()

  // let people know what's up
  echo "testing branch ${env.gitBranch}"
}
```

The remainder of the flow-script is comprised of serveral parametrized jobs which get the `env.gitBranch` passed as parameter (among others, if needed).

Be sure to allow concurrent builds for the workflow to catch every updated branch.