# Openshift retrieve branch name in jenkinsfile

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin, openshift-3

I have configured webhook on bitbucket server which points to Openshift. 
I want to get GIT repo url , git branch etc from webhook payload in my inline jenkinsfile but I dont know how to retrieve them. (Webhook triggers build though).

Is it possible ?

Here is my BuildConfig

```
apiVersion: build.openshift.io/v1
kind: BuildConfig
metadata:

  labels:
    application: spring-demo
    template: openjdk18-web-basic-s2i
  name: spring-demo
  spec:
  output:
    to:
      kind: ImageStreamTag
      name: 'spring--demo:latest'
  runPolicy: Serial
  source:
    type: None
  strategy:
    jenkinsPipelineStrategy:
      jenkinsfile: |-
        pipeline {
        agent {
          label 'maven'
        }
        stages {
          stage('Build') {
            steps{
               sh "echo ${env.BRANCH_NAME}"  <<<<------------- this is null 
            }
          }
        }
        }
    type: JenkinsPipeline
  triggers:
    - bitbucket:
        secretReference:
          name: yoyo
      type: Bitbucket
```

--Thanks.

Comment: Any solution to this?

Answer (score -1):

According to [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24746051/git-environment-variables-for-use-in-executing-jenkins-shell-scripts) and [some Jenkins documentation](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-belowJenkinsSetEnvironmentVariables), you need to install the [git plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin) on your Jenkins instance. Then you will have the variable `GIT_BRANCH` and `GIT_URL` available to you via  `${env.GIT_BRANCH}` and `${env.GIT_URL}`. **Make sure your branch names do not have slashes in them, (ex: `release/1.2.3`) as this confuses a lot of key tools in Jenkins**.

Alternatively as a last resort, in a [Jenkins scripted pipeline](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#scripted-pipeline) you can set your own environment variables via parameter or defaults (like "main") if you know you won't change your branches often.