# OpenShift Jenkinsfile / BuildConfig template access git branch name and other environment variables

Tags: git, environment-variables, jenkins-pipeline, openshift, jenkins-groovy

I have checked out [Openshift retrieve branch name in jenkinsfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50643501/openshift-retrieve-branch-name-in-jenkinsfile) but it doesn't work for me. I have had the necessary git plugins installed. However, everything is null / empty when referenced in Jenkinsfile or BuildConfig template.

`env.GIT_BRANCH` or `GIT_BRANCH` is empty.

Any advice and insight is appreciated.

Comment: Found the solution from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42383273/get-git-branch-name-in-jenkins-pipeline-jenkinsfile